# Not able to access Stack Overflow or any Stack Exchange site

Tags: support, stack-overflow

I am not able to access any site on Stack Exchange.

My internet connectivity is good and working. All other sites are opening successfully, but when I open any site on Stack Exchange, I get this message:

> Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to stackoverflow.com

Then I thought to uninstall my Chrome; after reinstalling Google Chrome version 31.0.1650.57m it again is not working.

I also tried Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer but neither are working. All other sites are opening on all the three browsers successfully. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you ping them?

Comment: it is saying request time out

Comment: But you do get an IP?

Comment: Can you do a [traceroute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute)? That might give some useful information.

Comment: @Bart:- Thanks a lot Sir! I found the solution :)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen:- I found the solution Sir! Thanks for your support!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a user networking problem and not related to the Stack Exchange network itself.

Comment: @animuson:- Yes Sir, I agree that it is not of any concern to the Stackexchange site but I thought that someone may get this problem in future so I thought to add it. But while posting my question I was not aware of the solution. P.S. Should I delete my question and answer as the issue is resolved now?

Comment: @RahulTripathi Just let it be. Just because it's closed, doesn't mean it can't be useful.

Comment: @Bart:- Ok Sir as you say. But it seems like I will end up getting downvotes on my answer as well as question. Never mind..Hope it will help someone in future but I really loved to find the solution for this! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this. I am sorry if that toubled you all. But I was not able to access it since 3 hours.

**Root Cause of the problem:** This problem can occur for any site when it is being viewed the same site over a router from more that one computer or application at the same time for a period of time. So this activates something in the server software that puts your IP address on a so called "BAND LIST".

**How I checked that Stackoverflow was up?**

I googled on a site which tells whether only you are not allowed on a particular site or it is down.

http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/www.stackoverflow.com

This site told me that it was not working for me.

**Resolution:**

1. You must go into your router.
2. Enter the setup section.
3. Select MAC address.
4. Select user defined.
5. Change a few numbers and letters in the MAC address.
6. Save settings and reboot your computer and reset your MODEM.

Thanks everyone for your support. But I also learned a very new thing today. Really Stackoverflow is a great knowledgeable site.

Comment: Stack Overflow cannot see your MAC address. So I doubt the ban was on the servers of Stack Overflow. (Apart from that, just randomly taking a number might, in theory, be a bad idea as it might be used by someone else.)

Comment: @Arjan:- Yes I know that there was no ban on the servers of the Stackoverflow. It was just that I was encountering this problem with Stackexchange site only so I thought that. But later when I found the solution then it was a different story!